# Can Mereology be bi-interpretable with Set Theory, in absence of the bottom object?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, mereology

This question is about synonymy between Set theory and Mereology.

David Lewis in [Mathematics is Megethology](https://www.andrewmbailey.com/dkl/Mathematics_is_Megethology.pdf) tried to reduce Set Theory to Mereology augmented with a singleton function. The following exposition is a formal capture of his Mereology.

Lets define a mereological theory $\sf M$ in mono-sorted first order logic with identity, add primitives of *part-hood* "$P$", and the partial unary function "$\mathfrak L $", denoting "*is the lable of*". Add the following axioms:

***Mereological Axioms:***

***M1*** $\textbf{Anti-symmetry: }X \ P \ Y \land Y \ P \ X \to X=Y$

***M2*** $\textbf{Bottom: }\exists X \forall Y: X \ P \ Y$

***Define:*** $X = \varnothing \iff \forall Y: X \ P \ Y$

***Define:*** $ X \ PP \ Y \iff X \ P \ Y \land \neg (Y \ P \ X)$

***Define:*** $atom(X) \iff \forall Y: Y \ PP \ X \to Y=\varnothing$

***Define:*** $ X\ P^*\ Y \iff atom(X) \land X \ P \ Y$

***M3*** $\textbf{Atomism: } \forall X (X \ P^* \ Y \to X \ P^* Z) \leftrightarrow Y \ P \ Z$

***M4*** $\textbf{Composition: }\\ \exists X \forall Y \ (Y \ P^* \ X \leftrightarrow Y=\varnothing \lor [atom(Y) \land \psi] ); \text{ if } X \text { is not free in } \psi $

***Define:*** $X = \bigl[Y \mid \psi \bigr] \iff \forall Y \ (Y \ P^* \ X \leftrightarrow Y=\varnothing \lor [atom(Y) \land \psi] )$

***Labeling Axioms***

***L1*** $\textbf{Labeling: } \mathfrak L (X)=\mathfrak L (Y) \to X=Y$

***L2*** $\textbf{Purity: } \exists X \ (\mathfrak L(X)=Y)  \leftrightarrow atom(Y) \land Y \neq \varnothing$

***L3*** $\textbf{Replacement: } \text  { if } \psi(X,Y) \text { is a formula, then: } \\ \forall X \neg \exists^{>1} Y: \psi(X,Y), \land   \\ B= \bigl[K \ P^* \ Y \mid \exists V (V=\mathfrak L(Y) \lor Y=\mathfrak L(V)) \land \exists X \ P \ A \ :\psi(X,Y)\bigr] \land \\\exists Z: \mathfrak L(A)=Z \\\to\\\exists Z: \mathfrak L(B)=Z $

***L4*** $\textbf{Infinity: } \exists I  \exists X: \forall Y    \ P^* \ X \bigl(\exists Z \ P \ X: \mathfrak L(Y)=Z \bigr) \land \mathfrak L (X)=I  $

/

In David Lewis account he didn't round the system with a bottom object, so a modified version of his system would be captured by $\sf M$-$\sf Bottom$ which is obtained here by removing $\sf Bottom$ axiom, re-defining atoms as objects devoid of proper parts, and stipulating the existence of a unique non-labeling atom $\varnothing$.

> Is theory $\sf M$ synonymous with "$\sf MK$ sans **Foundation** sans **Choice**"?

> Is $\sf M$-$\sf Bottom$ bi-interpretable with "$\sf MK$ sans **Foundation** sans **Choice**"?

My plan is to keep equality, and to identify part-hood $P$ with subset-hood relation $\subseteq$, and the labeling function $\mathfrak L$ with the singleton function $X \mapsto \{X\}$; and on the other hand to define $\in$ as: $X \in Y \iff \exists K \ P \ Y: \mathfrak L (X)=K$.

This way we come to identify classes with mereological totalities, and sets with labeled mereological totalities. All of this is following Lewis's own specifications. However, seeing that Lewis in his "[Mathematics is Megethology](https://www.andrewmbailey.com/dkl/Mathematics_is_Megethology.pdf)" doesn't agree to Bottom axiom, it appears to me that without this axiom the whole Ontology would be plagued with Ur-elements, and so it appears to be so hostile to Extensionality, that I think synonymy with Set Theory cannot be achieved. However, the weaker requirement of bi-interpretability might be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a version of Mereology in which there is no Bottom atom, and yet it is synonymous with the above theory, and if I'm correct about the above theory $\sf M$ being synonymous with MK-Foundation-Choice, then that answers this question to the positive.

The idea is to modify the underlying mereology as to have a kind of alien atom mereologically speaking, that is an object that doesn't overlap with any other object! This was done in a [prior](https://mathoverflow.net/q/412970/95347) posting. Now, to enable that here, we need to adjust composition as to forbid composing objects using that atom. Now, we use this atom to be the non-labeling atom. Here is the exposition of it:

**Language:** first order logic with equality, with primitives of $\subseteq$ standing for Part-hood, and $\{ * \}$ standing for the singleton function which is a partial unary function. The axioms are:

***Mereological Axioms:***

***Define:*** $atom(X) \iff \forall Y \subseteq X \, (Y = X)$

***M1*** $\textbf{Atomism: } \forall \ atom \ X \ (  X \subseteq Y \to   X \subseteq Z) \leftrightarrow Y  \subseteq Z$

***Define:*** $ X  \subsetneq Y \iff X  \subseteq Y \land X \neq Y $

***Define:*** $atom^*(X) \iff atom(X) \land \exists Y: X \subsetneq Y $

***M2*** $\textbf{Extensionality: }\forall \ atom^* \ X \, (X \subseteq A \leftrightarrow X \subseteq B ) \to A=B$

***Define:*** $X \ \mathcal O \ Y \iff \exists Z: Z \subseteq X \land Z \subseteq Y$

***M3*** $\textbf{Alien: }\exists X \forall Y: Y \neq X \to \neg X \ \mathcal O \ Y$

***Define:*** $X = \varnothing \iff \forall Y: Y \neq X \to \neg X \ \mathcal O \ Y$

***M4*** $\textbf{Composition: }   \exists X \forall \ atom^* \ Y \ (  Y \subseteq X \leftrightarrow  \psi( Y )); \text{ if } X \text { is not free in } \psi $

***Define:*** $X = \bigl[Y \mid \psi \bigr] \iff \forall \ atom^* \ Y \ (  Y \subseteq X \leftrightarrow  \psi( Y )) $

***Labeling Axioms***

***L1*** $\textbf{Labeling: } \{X\}=\{Y\} \to X=Y$

***L2*** $\textbf{Purity: } \exists X \ (\{X\} =Y)  \leftrightarrow atom^*(Y)   $

***L3*** $\textbf{Replacement: } \text  { if } \psi(X,Y) \text { is a formula, then: } \\ \forall X \neg \exists^{>1} Y: \psi(X,Y), \land   \\ B= \bigl[   K \mid K \subseteq Y \land \exists V (V=\{Y\} \lor Y=\{V\}) \land \exists X  \subseteq A \ :\psi(X,Y)\bigr] \land \\\exists Z: \{A\}=Z \\\to\\\exists Z: \{B\}=Z $

***L4*** $\textbf{Infinity: } \exists I  \exists X:   \forall \ atom  \ Y \subseteq X \bigl(\exists Z  \subseteq X: Z=\{Y\} \bigr) \land \{X\}=I  $

Now to interpret $\sf M$ in this theory, we take the domain to be all objects here, so there is no restriction, we keep the same equality relation, we re-define $P$ as

$X \ P \ Y \equiv_{def}  X \subseteq Y \lor X=\varnothing $

, and of course define $\mathfrak L$ as:

$\mathfrak L(X)=Y \equiv_{def} Y = \{X\}$

For the opposite direction, we work in $\sf M$, keep the same domain, and equality relations, re-define $\subseteq$ as:

$ X \subseteq Y \equiv_{def} X \ P \ Y \land (Y \neq \varnothing \to X \neq \varnothing) $

, and of course define the singleton function as:

$\{X\}=Y \equiv_{def} \mathfrak L(X)=Y$

Clearly the composition of these interpretations in each direction is the identity interpretation in that direction. $\small \square$

As regards the system $\sf M-Bottom$ mentioned in the question, I think it is not bi-interpretable with MK-Foundation-Choice, since it would be haunted by the same argument present in a [prior posting](https://mathoverflow.net/a/459098/95347).

Answer (score 6):

In a set-theoretic context, my view is that the most compelling concept of mereology is simply the $\subseteq$ relation, and so my conception of set-theoretic mereology is simply the theory of the $\subseteq$ relation.

So this doesn't answer your question, and I won't get into your theory, which is different from how I understand things, but some readers may be interested in this alternative approach to set-theoretic mereology, and so let me mention this alternative approach, which I introduced in my paper with Makoto Kikuchi:

- *Hamkins, Joel David; Kikuchi, Makoto*, [**Set-theoretic mereology**](https://doi.org/10.12775/LLP.2016.007), Log. Log. Philos. 25, No. 3, 285-308 (2016). [ZBL1369.03047](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1369.03047). arxiv:[1601.06593](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.06593).

Namely, we study the relation $\subseteq$ in a model of set theory, and we regard this theory as "set-theoretic mereology."

It is very easy to see in ZFC set theory that $\in$ is bi-interpretable with $\subseteq$ and the singleton operator, as we note in the paper, because of the following equivalences:
$$u\subseteq v\quad\iff\quad\forall x\, (x\in u\to x\in v)$$
$$y=\{x\}\quad\iff\quad \forall z\, (z\in y\iff z=x).$$
These show that from the $\in$ relation one can define both $\subseteq$ and the singleton operator. Conversely, we may define $\in$ from $\subseteq$ and singletons via
$$x\in y\quad\iff\quad \{x\}\subseteq y.$$
The conclusion is that the two accounts of set theory are bi-interpretable. Set-theoretic mereology with the singleton operator is bi-interpretable with $\in$-based set theory. You can define $\in$ from $\subseteq$ and $x\mapsto\{x\}$ and conversely.

But in regard to your specific axiomatization, I wouldn't have anything more to say.

Comment: Are they synonymous? If we don't have a bottom object, can they be bi-interpretable? Note that we agree on using Lewis interpretations of part-hood and the singleton (labeling here) function. Your background set theory is ZFC, the axiomatic system I posed is in relation to MK-Foundation-Choice. However, still examining these questions in YOUR theory may shed a light on how they'd fair here. So, to put matters in your milieu: is ZFC synonymous with set theoretic mereology(+singleton). Next question: is ZFC bi-interpretable with a set theoretic mereology (+singleton) that lacks bottom!

Comment: I personally think the answer to the first question is to the positive. But, it is the next question that makes me wonder. Taking away bottom would almost kill Extensionality, and even then the pattern of the emerging Ur-elements might not conform with simple removal of Extensionality from ZFC, and so kills bi-interpretability. This would mean that the most natural systems of Mereology even those augmented with the singleton function, since they lack the bottom object then they won't naturally lead themselves into bi-interpretability with Set theory. Only the bottom based Mereologies can!

Comment: The point is that the bottom axiom is necessary for having a natural bi-interpretability between Mereology and Set theory, and it becomes more essential if we further demand synonymy.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just not that interested in set theory without $\emptyset$. If you want urelements, that is a separate issue, and one must add a predicate to distinguish them from the empty set, but this would happen whether you are doing mereology or element-based set theory.

Comment: Thanks! But, I'm not speaking about set theory without $\emptyset$
. I'm speaking about bi-interpretability between Mereology without Bottom (which is more natural mereologically speaking) [like the theory M-Bottom], and Set theory meaning ZFC (or MK-Found.-C), which of course has $\emptyset$
 and doesn't have any Ur-elements. Notice that $\emptyset$
 need not be captured as a bottom object in Mereology, for example in Lewis system we have $\emptyset$
 interpreted as the mereological totality of all non-labeling atoms.

Comment: The existence of a bottom element or not cannot be important for bi-interpretation, since mereology without a bottom element is bi-interpretable with mereology with a bottom element. Interpret with pairs, where (a,a) represents a, and (a,b) represents the new element when a,b distinct, and define parthood on pairs to reflect this intention.

Comment: when you say (a,b) represent the new element, which new element you mean?

Comment: The new bottom element (if there wasn't one before). That is, in a mereological model without $\emptyset$, I can interpret a model which is just the same, except that now $\emptyset$ does exist. And this is a bi-interpretation.

Comment: forgive my thick skull, but what do you mean exactly, how the bi-interpretability goes?

Comment: Given a model of mereology with no $\emptyset$, I define $(a,b)\equiv (a',b')$ if either $a=b=a'=b'$ or $a\neq b$ and $a'\neq b'$. Define $(a,b)\subseteq(a',b')$ if either $a=b$ and $a'=b'$ and $a\subseteq b$, or $a\neq b$. Map $a$ to $(a,a)$ for the interpretation in the one direction. In the other direction, simply forget about $\emptyset$.

Comment: The existence of this bi-interpretation is why I find the big fuss about $\emptyset$ that one finds in some mereological contexts to be silly. Also silly: to fuss about parthood vs. proper parthood, since these also are bi-interpretable.

Comment: I'm too tired now to fathom that, I'll try to fathom it tomorrow after I have a good sleep. But for instance would that bi-interpretability achieve synonymy also?

Comment: No, because I am using pairs and a quotient by an equivalence relation (like interpreting $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$), whereas synonymy would mean that you don't use pairs or an equivalence relation.

Comment: Well, as I said I'm too tired now to fathom that. But, If you are firm on that then this is the answer to this question, which is to the positive both ways. Or at least in the milieu of set theoretic mereology you were speaking about (and I think it generalizes to the system I've presented if I got it right).

Comment: Ok, so your interpretation is to work on ordered pairs $(a,b)$ and define a new part-hood relation $P'$ over those pairs to the effect that $(a,a) \ P' \ (b,b) \iff a \ P \ b$, and $(a,b) \ P' \ (c,d)$ whenever $a \neq b$, also you want to define a new equality relation over those pairs that blurs the distinction between all $(a,b)$ pairs if and only if $a \neq b$. There is a problem, ordered pairing is not definable in Mereology. However, it's definable in Labeled Mereology (i.e. Mereology + Singleton), but in the latter you need to preserve the singleton function as well. to be continued..

Comment: cont...; there are some conundrums, for example most of the time when it said Mereology without Bottom, it is meant a system that proves the non-existence of a Bottom object. This means that your new part-hood and equality relations on the pairs, won't really interpret the older system, since you have a bottom for $P'$ but you negate that for $P$ in the original system. Not only that you need to keep the labeling function over the pairs, so you need to send the object representing the empty set in the original system to bottom in the new system. to be continued...

Comment: cont..., by then you'll need to manage the failure of Extensionality in the old system so that it becomes absent in the new system, so $a \to (a,a)$ won't be enough for that interpretation. Possibly you'll need to send all Ur-elements in the old system (the one without bottom) to bottom in the new system, and adjust matters accordingly. I think we may be able to manage it, but I'm not sure, in the particular system $\sf M-Bottom$ you have a unique non-labeling atom, and so failure of Extensionality is produced in a controllable manner, so I think we may be able to work the bi-interpretation.

Comment: just a corrective note, I think in your comment you wanted to say $a \subseteq b'$. [you wrote $a \subseteq b$].

Comment: I don't know if we can put matters this way: $(a,a) \ P' \ (b,b) \iff a \ P \ b$, and $(a,b) \ P' \ (c,d)$ if $a \neq b$, and if $c \neq d$ then  $(a,a) \ P' \ (c,d)$ if and only if $a$ is an Ur-element. As regards the new equality relation we need to blur distinctions between Ur-elements and $(a,b)$ pairs when $a\neq b$.

Comment: We don't need a pairing function, since on the usual meaning of the term, interpretations work with (uncoded) pairs directly---like how we interpret ℂ in ℝ. To interpret a theory, you define a class of k-tuples and an equivalence relation and use this as the domain of the interpreted structure. In the converse direction, when we have the bottom element, the domain is simply everything else. That directly is easy. It's like interpreting ℕ in ℤ. (And yes, your correction is right, I should have said $a\subseteq a'$ not $a\subseteq b$.)

Comment: still you need to take care of the labeling function and adjust for the Ur-elements. I need to think of it thoroughly and see for myself.

Comment: On further thought, actually the matter is more tricky than just blurring all empty objects. If we define membership as in the main post, then we'll have non-empty Ur-elements, and so we need to blur the distinction between any two sets having isomorphic membership graphs on their transitive closures, I think this will let us get rid of the copying destroying Extensionality in Mereology without bottom, and my enable bi-interpretability with "Mereology with bottom". Of course by Mereology I mean Mereology + singleton, or what I call "labeled Mereology"

Comment: Would [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/459098/95347) argument in a previous answer of yours would apply to destroy bi-interpretability between the two kinds of labeled Mereology.